# inserting a node in the nth position of a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

This is a hackerrank problem "to insert a node in the nth position of a linked list". From the problem's description, we are supposed to insert 10 at position 1.

`3 > 5 > 4 > 2 > Null` is an existing linked list and we have to insert 10 at index one. The output should look like this `3 >10 > 5 > 4 > 2 > Null`. This is my code:

```
def InsertNth(head, data, position):
    temp = Node(data)
    if (head == None):
        head = temp  #if head is Null then new node is the head
        temp.next = None
        #return head
    else:
        current = head
        i = 0
        while(i < position - 1):
        #for i in range(position-1):
            current = current.next 
            i = i +1
        next_node = current.next  #keep the address to the next element
        current.next = temp .     
        temp.next = next_node
    return head
```

The output I get using this code is `2> 10 > 5 > 4 > 2 > Null`, which is wrong. I tried a lot to fix, but the code looks fine to me. Can anyone please point out my error, with some explanation ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. There's a syntax error in your code (the `.` after `current.next = temp`), but when I fix that the output is `3 > 10 > 5 > 4 > 2` as expected. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Aran-Fey Now that I compare our solutions, they are identical except for the case where position == 0 needs to be explicitly handled separately but isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it. You need two checks in your `while` - one to make sure `i` does not cross `position`, and the other is to ensure that you do not fall off the end of the linked list (possible when `position` is greater than the size of your linked list).

If you are to insert at `position`, `i` should stop at `position - 1`. Then, set `cur.next` to be `temp`, and `temp.next` to be `cur.next`'s old value. You do not need a surrogate object for swapping pointers (`next_node`, in your code is unnecessary).

```
def insert(head, data, position):
    temp = Node(data)
    # handle all the base cases - empty list or position == 0
    if not head or position == 0:
        temp.next = head
        head = temp
    else:       
        cur = head
        i = 0
        while i < position - 1 and cur.next is not None:   
            cur = cur.next
            i += 1
        temp.next = cur.next
        cur.next = temp

    return head
```

[image]

Follow PEP8 standards please, snake case for identifier names only.

---

<sub>Challenge can be found at https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-a-specific-position-in-a-linked-list/problem</sub>.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I used your solution and it returns `2>3>10>5>4`, which is not correct, will you please mind looking at it again ? Also, thanks for letting me know about `PEP8 standards`, I will read it. One more question at at the end, `temp.next points out to current.next`, which in my understanding `10 points to 5` now, again `cur.next points to temp` which means `3 also points to 5`. aren't we supposed to do it such that `3 should point to 10, and 10 should point to 5` ?

Comment: @BIKI Consider `3 > 5 > 4` initially, and you want to insert `10` at position `1`. Cur should be `3` after the loop exits. Make `10 > 5` and then `3 > 10`, and you're done.

Comment: @BIKI I hope you pass "position" based on a 0-based indexing scheme. If not, you will need `i < position + 1`.

Comment: Thanks!! I got the logic now. But, why is it still returning `2>3>10>5>4` instead of `3 >10 > 5 > 4 > 2 ` ?

Comment: @BIKI Sorry, there were a couple of base cases I hadn't considered properly. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data;
        self.next = None;

class LinkdList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None;

    def insert(self, x, position):
        temp = Node(x);
        if position == 0 or self.head == None:
            temp.next = self.head;
            self.head = temp;
            return
        cur = self.head;
        for i in range(0, position-1):
            cur = cur.next;
            if cur.next == None:
                break;
        temp.next = cur.next;
        cur.next = temp;



    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head;
        while temp:
            print(temp.data, end= " ")
            temp = temp.next

l = LinkdList();
```

Comment: Please explain your code; for instance what you changed, and how it works.